# java keytool list certificates of pkcs12 -> Result empty

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keytool

I am trying to list the certificates stored in a pkcs12 file with key tool. The result is empty. When I open the pcs12 file with a external viewer, the certificates are shown.

I am using the following command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.pfx -storetype pkcs12
```

Does someone know what and where I am doing wrong?

thx

Comment: It seems perfect. Are you sure your store file has any certificate?

Comment: I've had issues working with pkcs12 under keytool using the sun provider, and even Oracle suggests using openssl in their docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfhb/index.html.  If you can verify the contents are in there, it may just be buggy.  PKCS#12 is a proprietary standard not owned by Oracle.